# get product attributes with its values

Tags: python, django, django-models

The table for product and product attribute is designed in a following way

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Attribute"
        verbose_name_plural = "Attributes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        Attribute, related_name="values", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("sort_order", "id")
        unique_together = ("slug", "attribute")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def get_ordering_queryset(self):
        return self.attribute.values.all()


class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="attribute_product", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        AttributeValue, related_name="attribute_value_product", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("sort_order",)
        verbose_name = "Product Attribute"
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Attributes"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.name} - {self.attribute.name}'

    def get_ordering_queryset(self):
        return self.product.attribute_product.all()


class ProductTypeAttributeValue(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute_value = models.ForeignKey(AttributeValue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product_type.name} - {self.attribute_value.value}'
```

I can get the list of attributes for a particular product by doing

`attribute = models.ProductAttribute.objects.filter(product=product)`

I can get the values both attribute values and the name of attribute

```
for a in attribute:
   print(a.attribute.name, a.attribute.attribute.name)
```

this will give me

```
Small Size
Medium Size
```

But i have no idea on how i can return in the following way

```
attribute [
        {
        name: color,
        slug: color
        values [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: R,
                value: Red
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: G,
                value: Green
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(**Product**
from where did this Product model come from?

Comment: There is a table Product in my code which is not shown here as i don't think it's that relevant to show. It just has name, slug, description.